# how to uniquely identify an hibernate sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

What's the easiest way to uniquely identify an Hibernate SQLQuery (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html) once it has been created and all it's parameters bound?

I've found this to generate a query key: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/spi/QueryKey.html.  But, that does not appear to be usable outside of hibernate internals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [@NamedNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) to uniquely identify an SQLQuery.

Comment: It does not look like NamedNativeQuery will accomplish what I want.  I want to identify the SQLquery along with the supplied parameters uniquely. Outside of hibernate, it'd be something like md5(select * from table where id = 5).  I'll look again at using QueryKey, since that seems to do that.